Should I inform the Review Board that approved presumably illegal data collection?
I've recently reviewed a paper where I think part of the data may have been obtained illegally, albeit in approval of the ethics review board.
Hence, I'm wondering whether there is a point in sending an email and informing the ethics board about potential issues from approving the relevant study. Particularly, I'm wondering whether any good will come from this, or whether I'm mostly gonna be ignored and burn bridges towards places.
Disclaimer: While I personally think that it is fairly obvious the data was in-part obtained illegally, IANAL and as such, may of course be wrong in my conclusion.

You may have committed to keeping the paper and your review confidential. If so, reaching out to the institution's review board may get you in hot water with the journal or its editor. So the first person I would reach out to would be the editor.

Definitely the editor - they can, on behalf of the journal that does not want to publish something that is in violation of ethical and legal standards, ask the probing questions.

Contact the editor with this suspicion.
The journal may have a policy on how to proceed.
